# how to distinguish between no time and midnight in COleDateTime class

Tags: c++, datetime, encoding, coledatetime

We use the `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss` date and time format API between frontend and backend.

However, there are cases that backend gets only the date since time wasn’t selected at the frontend side.
The `GET` call parameter will look like this:

```
startTime=16-11-2021
```

At the backend side, we use the `COleDateTime` class in order to parse the date and time. The problem is that the time in the case above is initialized to `00:00:00` when actually no time is sent.  I need a way to distinguish between no time sent and midnight as the actual time is significant in our system and there is a big difference between no time sent and midnight.

It seems that the `ParseDateTime` function expects to get a flag in its second parameter `VAR_TIMEVALUEONLY` to Ignore the date portion during parsing.
So for that, I need to implement a parse function in order to know if I got the time or not where it is expected that the `ParseDateTime` function would be set as an undefined time like `-1` when no time is sent.
Is there a way to distinguish between no time to midnight in `COleDateTime` class? If not, maybe you have another way I can use public libraries like `<chrono>` which could solve my problem?

Comment: How about making it a `std::pair<COleDateTime, bool>` instead? The bool could be used to say if the `COleDateTime` contains a time or not.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::optional<COleDateTime>` is probably a better expression of the concept.

Comment: @RaymondChen The date part isn't optional if I understood it correctly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, I missed that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`COleDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=msvc-170) has a function [`GetStatus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=msvc-170#getstatus) that is able to tell if the object has no value at all.  In all other cases, it's valid.  This means that there is no distinction between "no time" and midnight. The type seems [designed to encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/coledatetime-class?view=msvc-170#remarks) an absolute point in time.  Date-only or time-only hijack this encoding with 0 components.  No-date can easily be spotted, since numbering of date start at 0100-01-01 and cannot be confused with 0000-00-00. Nothing supports the spotting of no-time.

If you need a better handling of time uncertainty, this format is not suitable as it is. Unfortunately,  most other common alternatives have similar issues.   `<chrono>` would offer an equivalent feature which is the [`time_point`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point).  It also supports [dates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/year_month_day) and [time of day](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/hh_mm_ss) separately, with lots of conversion.  Boost has similar limitations,  as does [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) (unless you'd misuse the milliseconds, which would look weird).

As you get the time from the front end in `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss` or `DD-MM-YYYY` format, it's pretty easy for you to parse if there is or not time.  The simplest would probably to create a `DateTimeWrapper` to wrap `COleDateTime` together with `isTimeAccurate` indicator.